# What is the working range of TRUBLUE auto belay?

Tags: rock-climbing, belaying

The local climbing gym has several TRUBLUE auto belays but one can soon tire of the same routes. Will the auto belay work if one climbs a route next to it? At what angles does it still arrest a fall?

I found [this mention](https://headrushtech.com/blogs/auto-belay-safety-best-practices.html) of belay lanes but it only cites swinging and webbing wear as factors, not potential arrest failure.

Answer (score 7):

Its not that it won't catch you, its that if you are outside of your lane it will cause a pendulum fall and you might swing into someone else or the wall.

As it is their gear and climbing outside your lane will cause extra wear and tear, in addition to causing risk to other people, the courteous thing to do is to respect the rules and stay inside your climbing lane.

A better solution to the boredom caused by repetitive climbing would be to ask the staff if they could change the holds on the routes.

Comment: Or volunteer as a route setter and set routes yourself. I had unlimited access to the back for setting routes at my local gym. As long as you don't set crap routes they really like the free labour.